# How do I draw on canvas using finger?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to make kinda drawing thing via .NET Maui. I have read the documentation and now I can draw shapes via command. But I have no idea how I can do this using touch event (drawing with finger). Do you know how I can make this? Do you know any guide or documentation about that? What I should read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.NET MAUI Community Toolkit` package and then use its [DrawingView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview).The `DrawingView` provides a surface that allows for the drawing of lines through the use of touch or mouse interaction.

Here's the steps below on how to use it:

**1**. Install the `CommunityToolkit.Maui` nuget package

**2**. Call the extension method in your MauiProgram.cs file as follows:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        
        // Initialise the toolkit
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

        // the rest of your logic...
    }
}
```

**3**. Add the namespace in your Xaml:

```
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
```

**4**. Finally, consume it in your Xaml like below:

```
            <views:DrawingView
                x:Name="DrawView"
                BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                WidthRequest="200"
                HeightRequest="200"
                IsMultiLineModeEnabled="True"
                LineColor="Red"
                LineWidth="1"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```