# .NET MAUI and InkCanvas-like capability

Tags: .net, maui

I'm trying to find out if .NET MAUI has support for tablet pens and inking like the InkCanvas control in UWP and WPF.

I've looked at many, many MAUI examples but I've not found a single mention support for inking. It seems to me that ink support is a no-brainer for a lot of LOB tablet solutions and it's apparent lack in MAUI is puzzling to me. Does anyone have any information on pen support for tablets in MAUI?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it supports a pen the way you want, but did you see the `DrawingView` in the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit? https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui

Comment: Yes, this looks like it will do the job thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you can use `.NET MAUI Community Toolkit` package and then use its `DrawingView`. The `DrawingView` provides a surface that allows for the drawing of lines through the use of touch or mouse interaction. For more details, you can refer to [How do I draw on canvas using finger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859585/how-do-i-draw-on-canvas-using-finger/73861297#73861297) on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like just the thing, thanks!