# Draw Line on Canvas Based on Mouse Movement in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I'm trying to build an application like MS paint where there's a pencil icon that can draw a line (freehand line) when the user moves the mouse while holding the left-click button of the mouse. Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Yes, I have very good idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you can use [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit package](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) and then use its [DrawingView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview).

The [DrawingView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview) provides a surface that allows for the drawing of lines through the use of touch or `mouse interaction`. For more details, you can refer to [How do I draw on canvas using finger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859585/how-do-i-draw-on-canvas-using-finger/73861297#73861297) on how to use it.